# How is electron-updater able to find my repository?

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater, github-release

I have a repository that utilizes `electron-updater` for auto update. The weird thing is, it has no any code whatsoever pointing where the release updates are stored (I store it in GitHub releases), but somehow the `autoUpdater.checkForUpdatesAndNotify()` still works. There is github remote `origin` but I doubt it's being used by `electron-updater` to find the repository. I don't use any GitHub token either.

The way I release update:

- Increase the `version` in `package.json`
- Run `electron-builder`, producing `.AppImage`
- Create new release draft in my repository's GitHub releases
- Upload the `.AppImage` file to the draft's assets and modify the draft's tag
- Download the previous release, and then open it
- Voila! The update works. But how?

It's worth mentioning that if `latest-linux.yml` is missing from the latest release's asset, it will throw `404` error and refuse to update despite knowing the latest version's tag.

Here's the repository I'm talking about: https://github.com/SnekNOTSnake/fresh-update/releases

Also, is this how normal people release their electron app? I tried the `electron-builder --publish` way, but it's troublesome compared to the manual steps above.

Comment: "electron-builder automatically creates app-update.yml file for you on build in the resources (this file is internal, you don’t need to be aware of it)." - https://www.electron.build/auto-update and indeed, it contains: `owner: SnekNOTSnake, repo: fresh-update, provider: github`

Comment: You're right! There's this `resources/app-update.yml` containing those information. But still, no clue where does `electron-builder` get those info from. Do you publish your electron apps manually? Or do you use the `electron-builder --publish` thing?

Comment: "There is github remote origin" thats exactly how its doing that :) So if you clone the sources and build the app with those sources, it knows exactly where to get it from. Ref: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/28cb86bdcb6dd0b10e75a69ccd34ece6cca1d204/packages/app-builder-lib/src/util/repositoryInfo.ts#L12 - I've never done anything with this framework though.

Comment: You are correct for the second time! I never thought the `.git` folder is able to be utilized by other programs. Thank you for your enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Caramiriel in the comment section above for the enlightenment.

How `electron-updater` knows where to find the repository is from `resources/app-update.yml` inside the produced `.AppImage` file.

The `app-update.yml` file is produced by `electron-builder` using the information from `git remote get-url origin` (if available).

I proved it by changing the `origin`'s url to `https://github.com/SnekNOTSnake/tofu-tracker.git` and build the AppImage, and (surprisingly enough) the `repo`'s value became `tofu-tracker`.